cannot access USB webcam within Raspian OS in a VM
I have been trying to get some code that I got from github to run but I keep getting the error cannot open camera by Index.I am using opencv.I am running raspbian os on a vm. my webcam shows up on lsusb, but I cannot take pictures with it
my webcam is a "logitech c270".
I am on vbox and I have webcam passthrough aswellas usb device on.
running fswebcam gives the following error
 fswebcam test_image.jpg
--- Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video0 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
Adjusting resolution from 384x288 to 352x288.
--- Capturing frame...
Timed out waiting for frame!
No frames captured.

running modinfo uvcvideo gives
modinfo uvcvideo
filename:       /lib/modules/5.10.0-15-amd64/kernel/drivers/media/usb/uvc/uvcvideo.ko
version:        1.1.1
license:        GPL
description:    USB Video Class driver
author:         Laurent Pinchart <laurent.pinchart@ideasonboard.com>
srcversion:     E47A6A23F7770184CE233C3
alias:          usb:v*p*d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v*p*d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v8086p0B03d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v29FEp4D53d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v2833p0211d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v2833p0201d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v1C4Fp3000d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v1B3Fp2002d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v1B3Bp2951d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v19ABp1000d00*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v19ABp1000d01[0-1]*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v19ABp1000d012[0-6]dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v199Ep8102d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v18ECp3290d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v18ECp3288d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v18ECp3188d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v18CDpCAFEd*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v1871p0516d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v1871p0306d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v17EFp480Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v17DCp0202d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v174Fp8A34d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v174Fp8A33d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v174Fp8A31d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v174Fp8A12d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v174Fp5931d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v174Fp5212d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v152Dp0310d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p5103d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0E8Dp0004d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0BD3p0555d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0AC8p3420d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0AC8p3410d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0AC8p332Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v06F8p300Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05E3p0505d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05C8p0403d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp8600d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp8501d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05A9p7670d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05A9p264Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05A9p2643d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05A9p2641d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05A9p2640d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v058Fp3820d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v04F2pB071d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v046Dp082Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v046Dp08C7d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v046Dp08C6d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v046Dp08C5d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v046Dp08C3d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v046Dp08C2d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v046Dp08C1d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v045Ep0723d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v045Ep0721d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v045Ep00F8d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0458p706Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0416pA91Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
depends:        videobuf2-v4l2,videodev,videobuf2-common,usb-common,usbcore,videobuf2-vmalloc,mc
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           uvcvideo
vermagic:       5.10.0-15-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Debian Secure Boot CA
sig_key:        4B:6E:F5:AB:CA:66:98:25:17:8E:05:2C:84:66:7C:CB:C0:53:1F:8C
sig_hashalgo:   sha256
signature:      25:FD:29:93:CD:F0:A2:83:71:B1:AC:99:FE:6E:D8:BA:4C:74:1B:0A:
                E8:14:96:1B:50:DA:32:B3:38:D9:25:32:07:B9:C5:09:2D:80:56:A3:
                24:CA:C6:E9:F4:29:BE:F5:46:BA:12:F2:6A:90:B8:90:DF:BB:5A:44:
                D4:DD:FF:CA:41:BA:67:C3:71:60:95:77:B5:93:71:78:97:73:3B:8F:
                DE:3E:CD:D0:36:9C:C9:0F:6D:F4:2E:16:C9:96:27:E0:A7:A3:DC:10:
                EC:32:11:4D:E7:81:B6:55:90:42:B3:50:40:12:DF:16:0F:71:1A:4F:
                D9:4E:E0:D1:38:CF:A4:2C:0B:67:B0:5B:B4:F2:76:28:F2:48:AF:FE:
                8B:A0:6B:39:81:39:F2:A9:A2:37:B9:1A:B2:48:0E:73:83:57:7E:99:
                8C:BC:BA:B3:88:EB:DE:8C:E2:7D:67:27:0A:A1:BD:15:A8:18:22:E7:
                16:E0:E9:49:B9:ED:1D:5D:37:30:AF:20:47:CF:76:13:F0:93:58:A4:
                BE:BF:35:CC:39:4B:7C:5C:F7:03:21:2F:43:FC:56:E3:11:5E:30:86:
                FE:E7:E3:93:A9:56:27:2B:18:6F:73:C0:42:E2:59:91:21:45:C1:41:
                4A:61:C3:A3:3D:17:7E:F2:2B:A4:0F:0C:4A:2A:BB:93
parm:           clock:Video buffers timestamp clock
parm:           hwtimestamps:Use hardware timestamps (uint)
parm:           nodrop:Don't drop incomplete frames (uint)
parm:           quirks:Forced device quirks (uint)
parm:           trace:Trace level bitmask (uint)
parm:           timeout:Streaming control requests timeout (uint)

I tried adding myself to video group but I am already in video group.
running v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video* --all returns
v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --all
Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Card type        : UVC Camera (046d:0825)
        Bus info         : usb-0000:00:0b.0-1
        Driver version   : 5.10.120
        Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
                Video Capture
                Metadata Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps      : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Model            : UVC Camera (046d:0825)
        Serial           : 92974950
        Bus info         : usb-0000:00:0b.0-1
        Media version    : 5.10.120
        Hardware revision: 0x00000012 (18)
        Driver version   : 5.10.120
Interface Info:
        ID               : 0x03000002
        Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
        ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
        Name             : UVC Camera (046d:0825)
        Function         : V4L2 I/O
        Flags         : default
        Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
          Link 0x02000019: from remote pad 0x100000a of entity 'Extension 4': Data, Enabled, Immutable
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 352/288
        Pixel Format      : 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG)
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 0
        Size Image        : 102400
        Colorspace        : sRGB
        Transfer Function : Rec. 709
        YCbCr/HSV Encoding: ITU-R 601
        Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
        Flags             :
Crop Capability Video Capture:
        Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 352, Height 288
        Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 352, Height 288
        Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection Video Capture: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 352, Height 288, Flags:
Selection Video Capture: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 352, Height 288, Flags:
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
        Capabilities     : timeperframe
        Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
        Read buffers     : 0
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=32 value=32
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=32 value=32
 white_balance_temperature_auto 0x0098090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                           gain 0x00980913 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=64 value=131
           power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=2 value=2
                                0: Disabled
                                1: 50 Hz
                                2: 60 Hz
      white_balance_temperature 0x0098091a (int)    : min=0 max=10000 step=10 default=4000 value=1530 flags=inactive
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=24 value=24
         backlight_compensation 0x0098091c (int)    : min=0 max=1 step=1 default=0 value=0
                  exposure_auto 0x009a0901 (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3
                                1: Manual Mode
                                3: Aperture Priority Mode
              exposure_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=1 max=10000 step=1 default=166 value=667 flags=inactive
         exposure_auto_priority 0x009a0903 (bool)   : default=0 value=1

running modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=5000 quirks=0x80 did nothing...
and thats where I am...
here is the code I was trying to run:
#!/usr/bin/python3

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Display the image captured from the camera. Used as a test program to verify if OpenCV has been properly installed.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# automaticdai
# YF Robotics Labrotary
# Instagram: yfrobotics
# Twitter: @yfrobotics
# Website: https://www.yfrl.org
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import cv2
import time
import numpy as np

CAMERA_DEVICE_ID = 0
IMAGE_WIDTH = 320
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 240
fps = 0


def visualize_fps(image, fps: int):
    if len(np.shape(image)) < 3:
        text_color = (255, 255, 255)  # white
    else:
        text_color = (0, 255, 0)  # green
    row_size = 20  # pixels
    left_margin = 24  # pixels

    font_size = 1
    font_thickness = 1

    # Draw the FPS counter
    fps_text = 'FPS = {:.1f}'.format(fps)
    text_location = (left_margin, row_size)
    cv2.putText(image, fps_text, text_location, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                font_size, text_color, font_thickness)

    return image


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        # create video capture
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(CAMERA_DEVICE_ID)

        # set resolution to 320x240 to reduce latency
        cap.set(3, IMAGE_WIDTH)
        cap.set(4, IMAGE_HEIGHT)

        # Loop to continuously get images
        while True:
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # record start time
            start_time = time.time()

            # Read the frames from a camera
            _, frame = cap.read()

            # show image
            cv2.imshow('frame', visualize_fps(frame, fps))

            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # record end time
            end_time = time.time()

            # calculate FPS
            seconds = end_time - start_time
            fps = 1.0 / seconds
            print("Estimated fps:{0:0.1f}".format(fps))

            # if key pressed is 'Esc' then exit the loop
            if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:
                break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        # Clean up and exit the program
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        cap.release()

code exits with error:
python3 src/camera-test/cv_camera_test.py
[ WARN:0@0.021] global cap_v4l.cpp:999 open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index
[ERROR:0@1.070] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:158 getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range
OpenCV(4.10.0) /tmp/pip-install-_8kmh5mn/opencv-contrib-python_4b0ff950cd324340b3bc4b3ae8ba9cc4/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:973: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'


all that I tried I have given above.Sorry I am new to StackOverflow

Please do not LINK to code, rather post the relevant part inside of the question.

I am not using a physical raspberry pi but I am running raspbian on a vm

try this without OpenCV. use ffmpeg/ffplay or guvcview. if that too fails, it's not an OpenCV issue. then you know it's not a programming issue either, but a question for [su].

@ChristophRackwitz he used fswebcam at the very top.

@christophrackwitz I tried using ffmpeg and vlc to get a video stream going but they are not able to access the camera or time out

What happen if you change this index to one: CAMERA_DEVICE_ID = 1?

@toyota supra I am sorry but I am very new to this concept, can you specify where the index is located?

Change this CAMERA_DEVICE_ID = 0 to : CAMERA_DEVICE_ID = 1

you can safely ignore his attempts to help. the issue has nothing to do with OpenCV, so his suggestion to change the camera index to the OpenCV VideoCapture is pointless.

@toyota supra as said by christoph rackwitz changing the index to 1 had no effect on the output

@ Christoph Rackwitz. I'm talking about Linux, but  not OpenCV.

@joshuathomas do you have any other video devices listed under /dev/, aside from video0? I'm guessing not. so you can safely skip the debate about indices. if you do, please also probe those devices for their capabilities.

@joshuathomas. Your code is working. Estimated fps:496.6
Estimated fps:453.3
Estimated fps:482.1
Estimated fps:496.7
Estimated fps:483.3
Estimated fps:481.8
Estimated fps:512.2
Estimated fps:480.4

@christop rackwitz there are 2 devices listed below /dev/ video0 and video1 but they both disappear if i unplug my webcam

ok good, so try accessing and getting a video feed from each of those in turn. I'm sure the second one, video1, will fail to open, because you already tried that. does opening the first succeed?

@christoph rackwitz as i had already mentioned i was Unable to get  a video feed from the devices while using both mplayer and vlc as well as ffmpeg

I'd recommend investigating the means by which the USB device is passed from the host to the guest. look for help specific to the VM technology you use. I don't see you specify this. that broadly falls under [su].

@christoph rackwitz finally figured it out, the usb controller for the vm was set to usb2.0 instead of 3.0, thank you for your help tho:)

curious! I would not have guessed that at all. if this question is reopened, you should definitely post an answer to that effect. please make sure to update your question to state the VM technology/technologies involved (virtualbox, vmware, something else, ...). you said "vbox". please elaborate on that, perhaps with a version number and info on the host system.

now's the time to post your findings as the solution
